# Using SQL to retrieve XML attribute values

Tags: sql, xml

Let's say I've got a document that has a corresponding XML metadata file as shown below. This XML file contains index fields pertaining to the document:

```
<Document>
    <Indices>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>DOCID</indexName>
            <indexValue>49626502</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>EMPLOYEEID</indexName>
            <indexValue>248572405</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>LASTNAME</indexName>
            <indexValue>BROWN</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>FIRSTNAME</indexName>
            <indexValue>RALPH</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>CITY</indexName>
            <indexValue>PORTLAND</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>STATE</indexName>
            <indexValue>OR</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
    </Indices>
</Document>
```

I've loaded the XML file into a SQL table where I will then extract the attribute values and load them into another table. I've got thousands of these files. The way the metadata files were generated, if the source system did not have a field populated, let's say CITY or STATE, the XML tag was not created in the file. The challenge I am running into is the metadata files lack uniformity or consistency because one may have more index values than another (based on what was populated vs. blank in the source system).

Here is how I am extracting the attributes to load into a different table:

```
SELECT 

DOCID = CASE WHEN XMLDATA.exist('/Document/Indices/IndexField[indexName="DOCID"]') = 1 then XMLData.value('(//*[local-name()="indexValue"])[1]','varchar(max)') else NULL end,

EMPLOYEEID = CASE WHEN XMLDATA.exist('/Document/Indices/IndexField[indexName="EMPLOYEEID"]') = 1 then XMLData.value('(//*[local-name()="indexValue"])[2]','varchar(max)') else NULL end,

LASTNAME = CASE WHEN XMLDATA.exist('/Document/Indices/IndexField[indexName="LASTNAME"]') = 1 then XMLData.value('(//*[local-name()="indexValue"])[3]','varchar(max)') else NULL end,

FIRSTNAME = CASE WHEN XMLDATA.exist('/Document/Indices/IndexField[indexName="FIRSTNAME"]') = 1 then XMLData.value('(//*[local-name()="indexValue"])[4]','varchar(max)') else NULL end
```

For each field, I am first running this to make sure it exists in the XML file:

**XMLDATA.exist('/Document/Indices/IndexField[indexName="DOCID"]') = 1**

Then, I am pulling a positional value for indexValue:

**XMLData.value('(//*[local-name()="indexValue"])[1]','varchar(max)')**

The issue I am running into is if there are XML tags missing from the file, it throws off the positional indexValue for subsequent fields.

My question is- based on the XML format provided, how can I extrapolate the indexValue for a given indexName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion: Use *old-fashionded-pivot* with `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`. Missing values will just appear as `NULL`.

The CTE `DervivedTable` will first create a *normal* table with row-wise data. The rest is kind of `pivot`:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,XmlData XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1,'<Document>
    <Indices>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>DOCID</indexName>
            <indexValue>49626502</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>EMPLOYEEID</indexName>
            <indexValue>248572405</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>LASTNAME</indexName>
            <indexValue>BROWN</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>FIRSTNAME</indexName>
            <indexValue>RALPH</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>CITY</indexName>
            <indexValue>PORTLAND</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>STATE</indexName>
            <indexValue>OR</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
    </Indices>
</Document>')
,(2,'<Document>
    <Indices>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>DOCID</indexName>
            <indexValue>2222 id</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>EMPLOYEEID</indexName>
            <indexValue>2222 emp</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>LASTNAME</indexName>
            <indexValue>222 last</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>FIRSTNAME</indexName>
            <indexValue>222 first</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>CITY</indexName>
            <indexValue>222 city</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>STATE</indexName>
            <indexValue>222 state</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
    </Indices>
</Document>');
```

--The query

```
WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,f.value('indexName[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS indexName
          ,f.value('indexValue[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS indexValue
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.XmlData.nodes('/Document/Indices/IndexField') AS A(f)
)
SELECT ID 
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN indexName='DOCID' THEN indexValue END) AS DOCID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN indexName='EMPLOYEEID' THEN indexValue END) AS EMPLOYEEID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN indexName='LASTNAME' THEN indexValue END) AS LASTNAME
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN indexName='FIRSTNAME' THEN indexValue END) AS FIRSTNAME
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN indexName='CITY' THEN indexValue END) AS CITY
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN indexName='STATE' THEN indexValue END) AS [STATE]
FROM DerivedTable
GROUP BY ID
```

The result

```
+----+----------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| ID | DOCID    | EMPLOYEEID | LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | CITY     | STATE     |
+----+----------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 49626502 | 248572405  | BROWN    | RALPH     | PORTLAND | OR        |
+----+----------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2  | 2222 id  | 2222 emp   | 222 last | 222 first | 222 city | 222 state |
+----+----------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

### UPDATE

You would reach the same with *normal `PIVOT`*:

```
WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,f.value('indexName[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS indexName
          ,f.value('indexValue[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS indexValue
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.XmlData.nodes('/Document/Indices/IndexField') AS A(f)
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM DerivedTable
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(indexValue) FOR indexName IN(DOCID,EMPLOYEEID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,CITY,STATE)
) AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

Find `IndexField` with the `indexName` value needed and extract its `indexValue`

```
declare @x xml = '<Document>
    <Indices>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>DOCID</indexName>
            <indexValue>49626502</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>EMPLOYEEID</indexName>
            <indexValue>248572405</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>LASTNAME</indexName>
            <indexValue>BROWN</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>FIRSTNAME</indexName>
            <indexValue>RALPH</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>CITY</indexName>
            <indexValue>PORTLAND</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
        <IndexField>
            <indexName>STATE</indexName>
            <indexValue>OR</indexValue>
        </IndexField>
    </Indices>
</Document>';

select DOCID=@x.value('(//IndexField[indexName[1]="DOCID"]/indexValue)[1]','varchar(max)')
 , NOFIELD=@x.value('(//IndexField[indexName[1]="NOFIELD"]/indexValue)[1]','varchar(max)')
 --, ..
```

Comment: This works if the XML data is loaded into a variable. How would you modify this to work against a SQL table? The raw XML data has been loaded into a table called Test in a column "XMLData"

I tried this: 

`select DOCID = XMLDATA.value('(//IndexField[indexName[1]="DOCID"]/indexValue)[1]','varchar(max)')
 FROM TEST`


And got this error: 

**XQuery [TEST.XMLData.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'**

Comment: Tested with @Shnugo's setup, runs OK. Nevertheless, his solution should have better performance, I agree.